# how to write AutoIt script on locked terminal

Tags: task, scheduler, putty, autoit

I have an issue, where I used windows task scheduler to run an autoit (.au3) script to send interactive commands to a second program, PuTTY which is used to send commands via a serial port (RS232) to an electrical equipment that accepts putty commands.

The problem here as I've read from other threads is that GUI commands don't run when the terminal is locked, and because of security reasons I can't have it running logged on all the time.

Is there a method to get putty to work without using "keyboard/mouse" commands?
here's the really simple script.

```
run ("C:\Users\Public\Downloads\putty\putty.exe")
sleep(1000)
send ("{TAB 4}")//all these commands select the saved configuration for the com port, and open the PuTTY console
send ("{DOWN 2}")
send ("{TAB 1}")
send ("{ENTER}")
sleep(600)
send ("{TAB 4}")
send ("{ENTER}")
sleep(600)
send("{ASC 83}")//this sends the five characters "START" while in the PuTTY console
send("{ASC 84}")
send("{ASC 65}")
send("{ASC 82}")
send("{ASC 84}")
send("{ENTER}")
sleep(3000)
winclose("COM3 - PuTTY")//closes PuTTY.exe
sleep(2000)
send("{ENTER}")
```

I've tried using ControlSend, but that doesnt work at all.

This is the command i used to get task scheduler to run putty.exe instead of opening it:

```
cmd /c start "" "C:\Users\Bobby\Documents\runputty.au3"
```

Comment: Instead of using AutoIt to automate PuTTY, have you considered just writing a program to communicate over RS232 directly? A console app like this will run even with the computer locked.

Comment: I tried, but while i successfully opened the port and sent a command, the program failed, because i have no idea how to do "handshaking/flow control" with the device, which is why i resorted to using third party progs

Comment: I'm afraid you're probably stuck, then. You may have to do this programatically after all, and just learn about handshaking.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code (at 1-st time you must to login manualy and confirm the fingerprint of server):

```
Func _runSshCommand($plinkUser, $plinkHost, $command, $password = "", $timeoutInMs = 0)
 $plinkFile = "c:\putty\plink.exe"
 $runThis = @ComSpec & " /c " & $plinkFile & " -batch " & $plinkUser & "@" & $plinkHost
 If $password <> "" Then $runThis &= " -pw " & $password
 $runThis &= " " & $command
 $plinkHandle = Run($runThis, "", @SW_HIDE, $STDIN_CHILD + $STDOUT_CHILD + $STDERR_CHILD)
 $plinkFeedback = ""
 $waitForOutputStartTime = _Timer_Init()
 Do
  Sleep(10)
  $plinkFeedback &= StdoutRead($plinkHandle)
  $stdoutReadError = @error
 Until $stdoutReadError Or ($timeoutInMs And _Timer_Diff($waitForOutputStartTime) > $timeoutInMs)
 If ProcessExists("plink.exe") Then ProcessClose("plink.exe")
 If $stdoutReadError <> 0 Then Return $plinkFeedback
 EndFunc   ;==>_runSshCommand
```

For details please visit this thread [AutoIt Plink Wrapper](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/128310-plink-wrapper/).
Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem: after i reinstalled the prolific serial port wire driver and then reconfigured my controlsend statement, it worked.